# how to copy Int array to int pointer using constructor in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert int array x to int *v.  here is my code . please provide me with optimal solutions and the reason behind it.

there is an error in this line. Instead of copying array value its taking garbage value. line v1=x;

```
class vector
{
    int *v;
    int size;
public:
    vector(int m)
    {
        v = new int[size = m];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            v[i] = 0;
    }
    vector(int *a)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            v[i] = a[i];
    }

    int operator *(vector &y)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            sum += v[i] * y.v[i];
        return sum;
    }
    void disp()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << v[i] << " ";
        cout << "\n";

    }
};
int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int x[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    int y[3] = { 4,5,6 };
    vector v1(3);
    //v1.disp();
    vector v2(3);
    v2.disp();
    v1 = x;
    v1.disp();
    //v2=y;
    v2.disp();
    int r = v1 * v2;
    cout << "R = " << r;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: passing arrays by pointer is an error prone practice. https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-array

Comment: You have two constructors: `vector(int)` and `vector (int*)`. Only the first one initializes `size` and `v`. The constructor `vector(int *)` does not initialitze `size` and `v` and hence produces undefined behavior.

Comment: You have a memory leak as you do not release memory allocated with new

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the assignment operator in your `vector` class:

```
  vector & operator=(int *a)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      v[i] = a[i];

    return *this;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the the line

```
v1=x;
```

May be, you are expecting it to invoke the second constructor which takes `int*` as argument. But it won't happen.

It can be seen as **Type Conversion from Basic type to Class type**. where we expect appropriate constructor will get invoked.
see http://www.hexainclude.com/basic-to-class-type-conversion/

But remember, Constructor will be invoked only once after the creation of object.

Here, in the line

```
vector v1(3);
```

the first constructor was already invoked. Then the line

```
v1=x;
```

won't invoke the second constructor now.

For every class, `=` operator is default overloaded . That is the reason why we can easily assign objects to one another.

Therefore, the line `v1=x` invokes default overloaded assignment `=` operator. 
Here, it treats address of array x i.e., `&x[0]` as address of class object. As it is not address of `vector class` object

=> it results a **Segmentation fault**.

**YOUR ANSWER**

To assign `int` array to `int pointer` i.e., to the member variable `int* v` of the `vector class`,

1. overload assignment operator `=` inside the class .

**or**

2. Initialize the class object to array in first line itself. i.e.,

`vector v1=x; // modify the class constructor to have size as a constant.`

Comment: Arrays are compound types, not basic types. It would be better to stick with standard terminology, rather than terminology made up by some quick "tutorial" on the internet.

Comment: _"For every class, = operator is default overloaded"_ Wrong

Comment: Then, how is it possible to assign class objects to one another in a class where = isn't overloaded ??

Comment: You can assign _when_ there is an `operator=`. To say there always is one is untrue.

Comment: That's what I mean by the term "Default Overloaded" where exceptional cases always exists.

Comment: Well, you said "every class".